# SNS subscription: filter breaks when StringValue is a JSON payload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

The SQS subscription is configured to filter messages based on the "appId" message attribute. Only messages where the "appId" attribute has a value of "Foo" are selected by the filter.

Here's an example of a message that the filter would accept:

```json
{
  "appId": {
    "DataType": "String",
    "StringValue": "Foo"
  },
  "header": {
    "DataType": "String",
    "StringValue": "some string value"
  }
}
```

The primary attribute that matters for message filtering in the SQS subscription is the "appId" attribute. However, altering the value of the "header" attribute to contain a JSON payload causes the filter to break. Since the filter is designed to focus solely on the "appId" attribute, any modifications to other attributes, such as the "header", should not change the behavior of the filter.

The following message will NOT be accepted by the filter:

```json
{
  "appId": {
    "DataType": "String",
    "StringValue": "Foo"
  },
  "header": {
    "DataType": "String",
    "StringValue": "{\"field\": \"value\"}"
  }
}
```

To replicate the issue using the AWS CLI, follow these steps:

```bash
aws sns create-topic --name my-topic
aws sqs create-queue --queue-name my-queue
aws sns subscribe --topic-arn <topic-arn> --protocol sqs --notification-endpoint <queue-url> --attributes '{"FilterPolicy":"{\"appId\":[\"Foo\"]}"}'
# this works
aws sns publish --topic-arn <topic-arn> --message '{"appId":"Foo", "header":"some string value"}'
# this does not
aws sns publish --topic-arn <topic-arn> --message '{"appId":"Foo", "header":"{\"payloadVersion\":\"2\"}"}'
```

Even though it matches the filter policy, modifying the "header" attribute to contain a JSON payload disrupts the expected filtering behavior, causing the issue.

**IMPORTANT:**

Just to let you know, if the filter is removed, the message with the JSON payload is also delivered to the queue.

Comment: Can you please elaborate. explain your question in details so that you can get a help ?

Comment: I have also witnessed this behaviour if a JSON string is included in the message attributes.